# How do I get the Browser UI language in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I used this.

```
window.navigator.browserLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

It works in IE,Chrome,but in Firefox ,it seems to present the language I set in `tools>options>content>languages`

What should I use to show the Firefox UI Language.

Comment: There's seems no way to do it. I guess.[navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.language) has no standard definition cross browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox it is not possible to detect the UI language. Only the country the user is in. so I recommend you to keep the `window.navigator.language` part and trust that the most people speak the language of the country they are in.

Comment: But this way in Chrome will get the UI language.

Comment: I know and i cannot help it.

Comment: Thks anyway. I don't think this is possible.